# MariaDB: How to store a Table name into a variable?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to use multiple times a table name into a query. To avoid repeating it I want to store the name into a [User-Defined Variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html).

What is wrong with this query?

```
SET @tableName := 'de-Table'
SELECT * FROM @tableName;
```

In MariaDB the error is cryptic and (as usual) doesn't help at all:

```
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM @tableName' at line 3 */
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You're missing the delimiter (`;`) between the two statements.

Comment: And mysql does not do variable substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use dynamic MySQL if you want a variable to be the table name.  The following should work, if you're doing this directly from MySQL:

```
SET @tableName = 'de-Table';
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @tableName);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: @Nick And hence we've just seen how coding errors get propagated across a code base :P

Comment: I can't write :) in 15 characters!

Comment: First of all, thank you for all the answers. 

I am less than a newbie with MySQL/MariaDB but I am frankly surprised by how difficult it is to perform any simple task: use variables (even CSS understood how important they are!), finding the delta between values in consecutive rows, database backup without stopping the service, restore without dropping all existing rows in a table, mysqldump filtered by a query... For each problem there is a solution, but it is usually more counterintuitive than it should be. BTW I am lazy Python programmer. Sorry if I offended somebody.